# Operand returns different object

Tags: c++, object, operators

So I am making a program that has two classes monomial and polynomial.  Basically a Polynomial is just an array of monomials.  I need to create an `operator +` to add two monomials and return a polynomial.  So far I have declared Polynomial as a friend class in monomial and friend `Polynomial operator+(const Monomial& a, const Monomial& b);` in class `Polynomial` but it doesnt seem to work.

```
friend Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial& a, const Monomial& b);
```

and

```
friend Polynomial operator+(const Monomial& a, const Polynomial& b);
```

both work fine so im very confused were the issue lies.

Comment: [This](http://www.codingunit.com/cplusplus-tutorial-friend-function-and-friend-class) might be helpful...

Comment: "... but it doesnt seem to work."  If that's limited depth of detail we're going to get from the above question, the depth of the answers below is the appropriate response. ***What*** doesn't seem to work ? What (if any) errors are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example program that compiles cleanly, of course the contents of Monomial and Polynomial can be changed to your liking.

```
#include <vector>
class Monomial
{
public:
    Monomial() : A(0), x(0) {}
    int A;
    int x;
};
class Polynomial
{
public:
    Polynomial() {}
    Polynomial(const Monomial& a, const Monomial& b) {
        monomials.push_back(a);
        monomials.push_back(b);
    }
    std::vector<Monomial> monomials;
};
Polynomial operator+(const Monomial& a, const Monomial& b)
{
    return Polynomial(a, b);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Monomial a;
    Monomial b;
    Polynomial poly = a + b;
    return 0;
}
```