# Issue with overloading operator+

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to write a program which will eventually be able to be able +,-,*,/,solve,(etc) polynomials. I'm starting off with a simple case of trying to add two monomials and will slowly build upon it. I'm trying to overload the + operator but I keep getting the error:

> error no match for 'operator+' in 'm1 + m2'

In main I call it like such:

```
Monomial m1(2,3);
Monomial m2(3,3);
Monomial result;
result = m1 + m2; // I get an error when trying to do this.
```

In my Polynomial class header I have it defined as:

```
friend Polynomial operator+ (const Monomial&, const Monomial&);
```

The way I have implemented is:

```
Polynomial operator+(const Monomial& mono1, const Monomial& mono2){
    Polynomial poly;
    poly.coef = mono1.coef + mono2.coef;  // coef stands for coefficient
    poly.exp = mono1.exp;                 // exp stands for exponent
    return poly;
}
```

* Note I'm just trying to make operator+ work first before I dive into the actual case of different exponents and such. This is just the barebones of a simple case. 
I pass in m1(2,3) which is 2x^3, m2(3,3) is 3x^3 which should equal 5x^3 clearly, but I get an error. Don't worry about the printing the result part I have that figured out.

Comment: Can you please post the *complete* error message? It often contains hints to what it expects as well as a close match.

Comment: Also, how are `Polynomial` and `Monomial` related? (As you try to assign a `Monomial` variable with a `Polynomial` type.)

Comment: Have you even included the `Polynomial` class header file?

Comment: Why is result a Monomial when your operator+ member returns a Polynomial? Is Polynomial a derived class of Monomial?

Comment: Can you show us how your header files are laid out please?

Comment: Perhaps between the [two of you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850275/operand-returns-different-object), some kinks can get worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Polynormial` and `Monomial` have no real relationship, try this:

```
Monomial m1(2,3);
Monomial m2(3,3);
Polynomial result;
result = m1 + m2;
```

Comment: I tried that before and retried it again just now, however it still gives me the same error. Wait I just tried moving the function to the polynomial class from the monomial class but that did not solve the problem. However, when I moved the implementation above main, it works just fine. Why is that? Why can't I implement it in one of the classes? Is my implementation or declaration/definition wrong?

Comment: The C++ compiler parses the program from top to bottom, so it doesn't know there is an operator+ for Monomials if there is no declaration of the operator before the function that is using it.

Answer (score 0):

first, may be your `operator+` should return a `Monomial`.

But your issue is related to C++ scoping.
The friend prototype declaration is scoped to the `Monomial` class,
and cannot be used by the compiler when you latter write:

```
result = m1 + m2;
```

You need a prototype of operator+() to be visible in that scope, before your statement.
So you have to copy that prototype and declare it before (or have the implementation appearing before).